# Route to default not found 'catch all' address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm trying to route URLs like `stats/non-existent-page` to a default 'not found' page, where I'd like to display a 'Did you mean' suggestion along with a not found message, how can I route all non-existent URLs to a default controller/action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
match 'stats/*path' => 'default#non_existent'
```

Add this after your other 'stats/..' urls , This will route your all stats/* paths to the controller action mentioned with `path` variable you can use to determine your 'did you mean' suggestion..